# Can't seem to trigger error_message to display with django3?

Tags: django, django-3.0

I was working through the Django3 tutorial and doing some of my own stuff with it.  I have this template `sales_orders/details.html`

```
<h1>{{ sales_order.number }}</h1>
{% if error_messsage %}
  <p><strong>
    {{ error_message }}
  </strong></p>
{% endif %}
<h2>Date: {{sales_order.date}}</h2>
<form action="{% url 'sales_orders:update' sales_order.id %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="totalAmount" id="totalAmount" value="{{ sales_order.totalAmount }}">
  <label for="totalAmount">Total Amount: $</label>
<input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

and these two views

```
def detail(request, salesOrder_id):
    # try:
    #     sales_order =salesOrder.objects.get(pk=salesOrder_id)
    # except salesOrder.DoesNotExist:
    #         raise Http404('Question does not exist.')
    # return render(request, 'sales_orders/detail.html', {'sales_order':sales_order})
    sales_order = get_object_or_404(salesOrder, pk=salesOrder_id)
    return render(request, 'sales_orders/detail.html', {'sales_order':sales_order})

def update(request, salesOrder_id):
    sales_order = get_object_or_404(salesOrder, pk=salesOrder_id)
    print("got sales order")
    try:
        totalAmount = float(request.POST['totalAmount'])
    except ValueError:
        print("totalAmountError")
        return render(request, 'sales_orders/detail.html', {
            'sales_order': sales_order,
            'error_message': "Amount must be a number.",
        })
    print(f"got total Amount {totalAmount}")
    if totalAmount < 0:
        print("returning error message")
        # return error_messsage
        return render(request, 'sales_orders/detail.html', {'sales_order':sales_order, 'error_message':"Amount must be postiive",})
    else:
        print("redirect")
        sales_order.totalAmount = totalAmount
        sales_order.save()
        # Return with httpresponserequest aftersuccessful
        # Dealing with post data, toprevent dobule posting
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sales_orders:results', args=(sales_order.id,)))
```

I started purposefully trying to raise errors with this to just get the `{% if error_message %} {{error_message}}` to show, but I can't seem to do it despite confirming I should be returning `return render(request, 'sales_orders/detail.html', {
            'sales_order': sales_order,
            'error_message': "Amount must be a number.",
        })` I can't see what is wrong with my code that the error_message is not appearing when I purosefully enter bad data.  Can someone tell me what I  am doing wrong?

Edit: And the urls

```
app_name = 'sales_orders'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('details/<int:salesOrder_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('update/<int:salesOrder_id>/', views.update, name='update'),
    path('<int:salesOrder_id>/results', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:salesOrder_id>/addToAmount', views.addToAmount, name='addToAmount')
]
```

Comment: Can you share your urls?

Comment: Ok just edited the post.

Comment: And you're definitely being sent to the update view and not back to the detail view? Can you check the form's action attr?

Comment: This is what the HTML says `<form action="/salesorders/update/2/" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="btEB6srzH2ONUrMZgQxSmhiDMgEs7gX2QnrWGUXyo0goDkIylYWmFDVLh7FQEnpc">
  <input type="text" name="totalAmount" id="totalAmount" value="2.58">
  <label for="totalAmount">Total Amount: $</label>
<input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>`.  Update is supposed to just be a post route that then redirects, so should it not be under my urls?

Comment: `sales_orders/details.html` the `s` is a typo?

Comment: Ok that was a issue. 

I got rid of the `{% if error_messsage %}` and I started getting the expected behavior - error messages appearing at the top of a fresh details page.  Is there something wrong with the way that template if statement is written?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the typo I made, I had to get rid of the update in my urls and things worked as expected as with the {% if error_mesage %}.  Update was only a post route in the way I had things and I think that was what causing my issue.